# Laravel 5.2 Chatter Forum Package errors

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, forum

I am using third party laravel forum library and i follow the steps in the tutorial but it gives the following error.

> Type error: Argument 2 passed to DevDojo\Chatter\Events\ChatterBeforeNewDiscussion::__construct() must be an instance of Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator, instance of Illuminate\Validation\Validator given, called in /home/mahmood/work/aalaauddin/vendor/devdojo/chatter/src/Controllers/ChatterDiscussionController.php on line 66

Can please someone please help?

Comment: Try to write this on top `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator` in this page `/home/mahmood/work/aalaauddin/vendor/devdojo/chatter/src/Controllers/ChatterDiscussionController.php`

Comment: Thanks Ahmad, however same error still there.

Comment: Can you share code of this page `ChatterDisc‌​ussionController.php`

Comment: The code is too long so here is the link for the github repo

Comment: If this is the [link](https://github.com/thedevdojo/chatter/blob/master/src/Controllers/ChatterDiscussionController.php), you should replace `use Validator;` with this `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator as Validator`

Comment: I replaced and it doesnt work here is the link https://github.com/thedevdojo/chatter/blob/master/src/Controllers/ChatterDiscussionController.php

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139073/discussion-between-ahmad-rezk-and-mohamud).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem cropped up while trying to post a discussion. What I did was to remove the type-hint from the constructor (in vendor/devdojo/chatter/src/Events/ChatterBeforeNewDiscussion.php) like so
 `public function __construct(Request $request,  $validator) { $this->request = $request; $this->validator = $validator; }`

and also  changed the
`Event::fire(new ChatterBeforeNewDiscussion($request, $validator));` to
`Event::dispatch(new ChatterBeforeNewDiscussion($request, $validator));`

(in vendor/devdojo/chatter/src/Controllers/ChatterDiscussionController.php)

I was then able to post discussions seamlessly!